# Combine sed commands to only list 5 results as well as show non-printable characters

Tags: shell, sed

I found two different **sed** commands shown below, however, I would like to have a *single* command to show both non-printable characters and limit the output to 5.

Limit the number of results displayed:

```
sed -n '1,5p;5q' filename.csv
```

Display the results, including non-printable characters:

```
sed -n 'l' filename.csv
```

Can someone please advise?

Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for this? `sed -n '1,5l;5q'`?

Comment: What Kent said, with filename:  `sed -n '1,5l;5q' filename.csv`

Comment: Or just `'l;5q'` for simplicity.If on the 5th line you quit, it's not like you really need to specify a range for the print commend, do you? You won't print line 6. You've quit by then.